# Making a ellipse object in libgx java android game

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have tried to make a ellipse object in libgdx. Sorry if i can't describe properly but im a newbie in java.

My code looks like:

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen{

MyGame game;
OrthographicCamera camera;
SpriteBatch batch;
...
Ellipse playBounds;

 public GameScreen(MyGame game) {
            this.game = game;
            camera = new OrthographicCamera();
            camera.setToOrtho(false, 1080, 1920);
            batch = new SpriteBatch();
            state = GAME_READY;
            touchPoint = new Vector3();
            pauseBounds = new com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle(1080-128,1920-128,128,128);
            playBounds= new Ellipse()
        }
```

...

```
public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1F, 1F, 1F, 1F);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        camera.update();
        generalupdate();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(Assets.sprite_bg, 0, 0);
        switch (state){
            case GAME_READY:{
                batch.draw(Assets.sprite_startScreen, 0, 0);
                batch.draw(Assets.sprite_playButton,218,800,644,225);
                break;
            }
```

Basically it draws background, a welcome screen and a button(with "play" on it)
So here i made a touch detection.

```
        if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
            camera.unproject(touchPoint.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
        if (state==GAME_READY);
        if (playBounds.contains(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {
            state=GAME_RUNNING;
```

Drawing works fine but the problem is when i touch the button it doesnt work instead if i touch near it game starts as it should

Answer (score 1):

Alright, ignoring the several errors in the code which I will just assume were made here instead of the actual code, I believe the problem could be that you are not setting the values in the Ellipse. By this I mean the width, height, x, and y.

---

An nice way to do this would be to use the constructor:

Ellipse(float x, float y, float width, float height)

instead of just :

Ellipse()

---

That way you can set the values right away. Refer to [this website](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Ellipse.html) for more info in Ellipses for LibGDX.

If that doesn't solve your problem you may have to post a little more of the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Thank you for link,i deleted ellipse coordinates ...there were some numbers but the main problem is that i dont understand where x and y are ..i mean in a rectangle x and y are coordinates for button left corner but in a ellipse where are those?